# Is it possible to have a container prepopulated with a specific component through a prototype page in Hippo CMS / brXM?

Tags: content-management-system, hippocms

In an attempt to set up a new page with a single `vbox` container I'm able to get the container to show in the Channel Manager but this requires the CMS editor to add all of the individual components by hand. Alternatively we can place components directly on the page and through the configuration in the prototype but that does not allow the CMS editor to edit the component configuration (Info) or associate a document. The question is then, in an attempted compromise, is it possible to repopulate the container with a specific component so that the the CMS editor is provided a default set of components in the containers when creating a new page from a prototype/template page?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the key term you are looking for is **hst:prototypepages**

Their documentation can be found at https://documentation.bloomreach.com/14/library/concepts/hst-configuration-model/prototypepages-configuration.html but basically you can define the prototype having certain components already on the page - and possibly even default settings for those components.

A similar concept at the component level is the **hst:catalog**
You can define "component prototypes" with default settings for when they are placed onto a page.

Comment: Yes, these are concepts I've learned how to utilize as I've been trying to learn the options and capabilities of the Bloomreach platform however what I'm looking for is the capability for CMS editors to be able to create new pages that have most of the default setup in place but the ability to edit the configurations and/or documents bound to those components. Ideally I'd like a component that is "already on the page" as you mentioned in your example to be editable by CMS user's but it looks like CMS editor capability is elusive to components within a container.

Comment: Sorry, that should have been exclusive and not elusive.

Comment: If the prototype page has child nodes, those nodes will be included on every new (concrete) instance of the page.  so you can build out the default structure/content of a page, including component(s) and even settings for the component(s).  You can nest away!

Comment: Ok, this didn't work for me in my limited testing but to be fair it's highly complex and unintuitive from a typical CMS so I definitely could have gotten something wrong. I'll give it another stab and see if this works, if so perhaps you could modify your answer to explain a bit of this so that I can accept it at that point.

Comment: I recommend starting with a blank template/page and drag in and configure your components as desired.  Copy the resulting container contents into your new prototype page (from the JCR console).  The point of the node tree of a prototype page is to be the "prototype" or template of the starting point for new pages.

Comment: Yeah I tried this but it didn't seem to work for me. The crux of the problem was that for "pages" containers don't seem to be supported or at least I wasn't able to put catalog components into containers through the channel manager. On the other side components couldn't be editable in an instance of the prototype page until they are in a container from what I could find. So the transition from page to prototype page seemed to be a larger shift than I anticipated and the design I had up for one didn't transition to the other. I'll go back and retest this though to see if I overlooked something.